# Can the TestNG "Failed Tests" output use line breaks?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, tdd, testng

When I run my TestNG tests I get the following truncated output for failed tests:

```
Failed tests: retrievedDataFromService(com.mydomain.ServiceTest): The returned data is not correct:(..)
```

The actual string from the Assert.fail() is something like this:

```
StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder("The returned data is not correct:");
msg.append("\n expected = ");
msg.append("<xml>some data</xml>");
msg.append("\n was = ");
msg.append("<xml>some other data</xml>");
```

If I remove the line breaks from the message, everything is shown:

```
Failed tests: retrievedDataFromService(com.mydomain.ServiceTest): The returned data is not correct: expected = <xml>some data</xml> was = <xml>some other data</xml>
```

Is there a way to have TestNG display line breaks in the "Failed tests" output?

Comment: What OS your running your test on.

Comment: I'm running MacOS 10.7.5, using TestNG 6.3.1.

Comment: I am not on MacOS, so I can't give your perfect answer. Have you made your `msg.toString()`?

Comment: Yes I have.  This is it: Assert.fail(msg.toString());

Comment: Well I don't know what is the issue.I know for sure `\n` is allowed in MacOS, java and TestNG is not exception as well. Try to make simple helloWorld Program and run also try to run the TestNg test case for that helloWorld program with`\n`. See if you could catch something.